# i am trying to store my function call within an object

Tags: javascript, html, function, object, properties

i am trying to store my function call within an object, so when i refenence the property, it runs the function. this is the code i wrote, but its not working. this is my code so far.
html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tetris(test)</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleSheets/main.css">
    <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/jquery.1.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <svg id="container" width= "500" height= "650" style= "background-color: black" position= "relative">
      </svg>

  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var htmlNS = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";

function createShape1() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("container");
    var shape = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
        shape.id = "shape1";
        shape.style.width = "150px";
        shape.style.height = "50px";
        shape.style.fill = "orange";
        shape.style.y = "50px";
        shape.style.x = "150px"
        shape.style.position = "absolute"
        elem.append(shape);
    var shape2 = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
        shape2.id = "shape2";
        shape2.style.fill = "orange";
        shape2.style.x = "200px";
        shape2.style.width = "50px";
        shape2.style.height  = "51px";
        elem.append(shape2);
};
window.onload = randShape;
function createShape2() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("container");
    var shape = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
    shape.id = "shape1";
        shape.style.width = "100px";
        shape.style.height = "100px";
        shape.style.fill = "red";
        shape.style.x = "200px"
        shape.style.position = "absolute"
        elem.append(shape);
};
var shapes = {
    "shape1": createShape1(),
    "shape2": createShape2()
};
function randShape() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    shapes.x;
}
```

so if you have any suggestions to get my code to generate a random property of shape, each of which should generate its own shape.

Comment: `"shape1": createShape1()` here you a calling the function ... `shapes.x` here you are referring to either `shapes[0]` or `shapes[1]` - neither of which exist,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS:

```
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var htmlNS = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";

function createShape1() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("container");
    var shape = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
        shape.id = "shape1";
        shape.style.width = "150px";
        shape.style.height = "50px";
        shape.style.fill = "orange";
        shape.style.y = "50px";
        shape.style.x = "150px"
        shape.style.position = "absolute"
        elem.append(shape);
    var shape2 = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
        shape2.id = "shape2";
        shape2.style.fill = "orange";
        shape2.style.x = "200px";
        shape2.style.width = "50px";
        shape2.style.height  = "51px";
        elem.append(shape2);
};
window.onload = randShape;
function createShape2() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("container");
    var shape = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
    shape.id = "shape1";
        shape.style.width = "100px";
        shape.style.height = "100px";
        shape.style.fill = "red";
        shape.style.x = "200px"
        shape.style.position = "absolute"
        elem.append(shape);
};
var shapes = [createShape1, createShape2]
function randShape() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    shapes[x]()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was how to access the value and making the function call before accessing what function you wanted to call

```
var shapes = {
  "shape1": createShape1,
  "shape2": createShape2
};

function randShape() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
    (shapes["shape" + x]).call(shapes);
}
```

Comment: no i want to call the function. the randShape() function is suppose to call one of the two createShape function. which will have one of the 2 shapes displayed on the page.

Comment: I edited my answer, to only allow invocation after accessing its function value

Comment: this is my error: Uncaught TypeError: shapes[("shape" + x)] is not a function at randShape (file:///C:/Users/jmish/OneDrive/Desktop/projects/tetri(test)/js/main.js:41:24)

Comment: I made changes, this should work! Needed to add context to the invocation of shape and also the random index should be from 1 and not 0